# IWebElement.Text Property convert's Emoji's

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, character-encoding, emoji

### [`OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement.Text`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/P_OpenQA_Selenium_IWebElement_Text.htm)

> If you call Text Property and the HTML inner Text is "❌", you will get ":x:".
> If you take this Text "✅", the Return Value is ":white_check_mark:".

I looked up different Emoji and Unicode [References](https://unicode-table.com/de/2716/), but I could find, which code/charset this is.

### A Solution for me would be

1. If there is a method with the original Text as return value.
2. or if there is a library/packed, converting the code back to Unicode.

#### Code

```
string cItemText = cItem.FindElement(By.ClassName("im_message_photo_caption")).Text;
```

#### Update

Found out, that this code `:white_check_mark:`, is something called [shortcode/shortcodes](https://emojipedia.org/emoji/%E2%9C%85/), but no clue how to convert back to unicode.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried below code to get the unicode ?

Add a reference to Microsoft.JScript.dll

```
string result = Microsoft.JScript.GlobalObject.escape(inputString);
```

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9a09cb14-5eb3-4b74-9cf1-ac9e0ae641fc/convert-string-to-unicode?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: I hava a `.net 5.0` Framework. The JScript is in the `.net Framework`